# jQuery - $(this) on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I ran through the following Javascript to create a click function to toggle an active state and expand an element to show the full text.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

    var toggle = function(el, direction) {
        if (direction === 'open') {
            var content = $(el).toggleClass("active").prev();
            var curHeight = content.height();
            content.css('height', 'auto');
            var autoHeight = content.height();
            content.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 100).promise().then(setTimeout(function(){content.removeClass("limited")}, 650));       
        } else {    
            var content = $(el).toggleClass("active").prev();
            content.height(curHeight).animate({height: '70px'}, 100).promise().then(function(){content.addClass("limited")});
        }
    }

    jQuery(".togglefeaBtn").on("click", function(){             
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Read MORE') {
            $(this).text('Close');
            toggle(this, 'open');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Read MORE'); 
            toggle(this, 'close');
        }       
        return false; 
    });
});
```

The issue that I've noticed is that when loaded on an iPad $(this), when in the click function, or $(el), when in the toggle function return a blank value, however, $(this).text('...') works perfectly.

Is there an issue with the way I'm using the click function, or do touch devices require a different set up?

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile? It might be causing a change in the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `toggle($(this), 'close');` not `this`? The context of `this` hasn't been defined.

You can also change `$(el)` to just be `el`.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

    var toggle = function(el, direction) {
        if (direction === 'open') {
            var content = el.toggleClass("active").prev();
            var curHeight = content.height();
            content.css('height', 'auto');
            var autoHeight = content.height();
            content.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 100).promise().then(setTimeout(function(){content.removeClass("limited")}, 650));       
        } else {    
            var content = el.toggleClass("active").prev();
            content.height(curHeight).animate({height: '70px'}, 100).promise().then(function(){content.addClass("limited")});
        }
    }

    jQuery(".togglefeaBtn").on("click", function(){             
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Read MORE') {
            $(this).text('Close');
            toggle($(this), 'open');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Read MORE'); 
            toggle($(this), 'close');
        }       
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: `this` is referring the element clicked on during the event, when it's passed into toggle, the `var content` uses `$(el)` to return the click element as a jQuery object and get the element immediately before it. Changing `this` to `$(this)` and `$(el)` to `(el)` does nothing but reverse the semantics, either way it's getting a jQuery object.

Comment: Why not just send the jQuery object straight to the toggle function? `this` and `$(this)` are not the same. `$(this)` will refer to the element clicked (`$('.togglefeaBtn')`)

Comment: `this` refers to the javascript object that triggered the event whereas `$(this)` returns the jQuery object, either way, it makes no difference to functionality and still functions on Desktops but not on iPads.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the click event is firing, and it has to be passing the javascript object into the event due to the fact that the text is changing as defined by `$(this).text('Close');`. What I am confused about is the fact that `var content` is left blank because `el.prev()` can't be resolved for some reason, though `el.toggleClass("active")` fires off perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried unchaining the methods? Just use el.prev() and run el.toggleClass() as soon as you enter the function. I don't see this being the problem as toggleClass should `return this` and allow method chaining but who knows.. can you make a fiddle and I'll try debug it properly later if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to wrestle with this issue, I opted to take a much simpler route and scrap the Javascript method to animate the reveal and just use CSS Transform with max-height. The code got a lot smaller, and works nearly everywhere.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

    jQuery(".togglefeaBtn").on("click", function(){             
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Read MORE') {
            $(this).text('Close');
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).prev().css('max-height', '500px');
            $(this).prev().removeClass("limited");
        } else {
            $(this).text('Read MORE');
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).prev().css('max-height', '70px');
            $(this).prev().addClass("limited");
        }       
        return false; 
    });
});
```